# How use freemarker with inline template

Tags: freemarker

Can I use spring-boot with freemarker but I need to create my template in runtime, load from a db, I only find sample using the return in a controller

Answer (score 2):

At least if you don't need Spring MVC (`spring-web`) functionality, you can just use the FreeMarker API directly. You will need a `freemarker.template.Configuration` singleton bean (maybe the one that Spring creates for Spring MVC is sufficient, but creating your own is perhaps cleaner), and then you can use `new Template(null, someString, cfg).process(dataModel, outputWriter)`. If performance is a concern, you might want to cache the resulting `Template` objects of course.

Also note that if you provide a such `TemplateLoader` implementation, FreeMarker can load template directly from the database, (in which case you would use `Configuration.getTemplate(templateName)` to get the `Template` object). That has the advantage that then the templates in the database can be `#import`-ed/`#include`-ed, and also that FreeMarker will cache the `Template` objects for you. And of course, in case you need this for Spring MVC, then you could just do things as usual in Spring MVC, you don't need "inline templates".